# How to prove a certain parallelism in a triangle geometry issue involving incircle, circumcircle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> Given $\triangle ABC$ with incenter $I$ and circumcenter $O$. Let $D$ be the tangency point of $BC$ and ($I$). $AI$ cuts ($O$) at $X$. $DX$ cuts the perpendicular bisector of $AI$ at $S$. $AO$ cuts ($O$) at $K$. Prove that $OS\parallel DK$.

[image: Graph is here.]

My thought was to show that $AD$ intersects $SO$ at $SO$'s middle point.
Isn't so easy. I tried harmonic but failed.

How to deal with such middle points and perpendicular lines? I'm a bit of confused. Any idea welcomed.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Why don't you answer the question by ACB ?

Comment: I have changed your previous title "Geometry - interesting - multicenters and multimiddlepoints - parallel lines wanted." into something encompassing in a better way what this question is about (so I think... for example, the fact that this issue is "interesting" could be added to most questions here...). Do you agree ?

Comment: Again, why don't you answer to the question by ACB ? Is it an ongoing competition ?

Comment: Ever heard of the sharky devil lemma? https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c776104h1954097

Comment: It's from AoPS several days ago. I didn't exactly remember the source (sorry for this - maybe I should've clarified it first) -- To #Jean Marie#

Comment: I took a look at the problem. As it stays, the question does highly not respect the lines of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question - we have a problem, the source is unknown, and despite of the comments above, we have only the information "*it's from AoPS*". It's hard to search the whole AoPS, please give a more precise location. Your own effort to solve the problem is only the mention of trying to show that $AD$ intersects $SO$ in the mid point of $SO$, which is in general **false**. We also do not have a clear question. Please restate it properly.